# Maven Spring Boot Application startup failed - JmxAutoConfiguration.mbeanExporter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am using a Spring Boot project for 2 years now and I just tried to get a colleague involved but I could not get the repository to run on his computer. Therefore I have deleted my `.m2` folder and cloned the project myself again and I can reproduce the error but the problem is I am not able to fix it.

Spring Boot Version: 1.5.22.RELEASE . Any suggestions?

```java
2021-03-08 15:29:48.563 [restartedMain] INFO  d.a.s.SpringBootproject - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-08 15:29:48.709 [background-preinit] INFO  o.h.v.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.6.Final
2021-03-08 15:29:48.789 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@72d24d6a: startup date [Mon Mar 08 15:29:48 CET 2021]; root of context hierarchy
2021-03-08 15:29:53.456 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]
2021-03-08 15:29:53.677 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration.mbeanExporter
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:179)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:666)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:353)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:300)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1082)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1071)
    at de.myproject.project.SpringBootproject.main(SpringBootproject.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException: null
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:255)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getGenericParameterType(MethodParameter.java:397)
    at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$MethodParameterTypeProvider.getType(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:338)
    at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper.forTypeProvider(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:146)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1346)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1249)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1217)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodReturnType(ResolvableType.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1496)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:217)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:195)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:188)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:175)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:171)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:103)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
2021-03-08 15:29:53.679 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@72d24d6a: startup date [Mon Mar 08 15:29:48 CET 2021]; root of context hierarchy
2021-03-08 15:29:53.681 [restartedMain] WARN  o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Unable to close ApplicationContext
java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException: null
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:255)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getGenericParameterType(MethodParameter.java:397)
    at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$MethodParameterTypeProvider.getType(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:338)
    at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper.forTypeProvider(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:146)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1346)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1249)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1217)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodReturnType(ResolvableType.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1496)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:508)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1190)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:785)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:773)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:760)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:715)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1082)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1071)
    at de.myproject.project.SpringBootproject.main(SpringBootproject.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

What I have done so far:

- Fixed all dependencie warnings/errors with maven-resources-plugin
- Added the following parameter to my `application.yml`

```yaml
spring:
    jmx:
       enabled: false
```

- Tried to exclude the `JmxAutoConfiguration.class` in the `@SpringBootApplication` class
- Checked that Java 8 is used in Eclipse IDE.

Any help is appreciated.

//EDIT
@Deviprasad Sharma

This is the spring boot config:

```
package de.myproject.project;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import de.all4cloud.scan4cloud.config.JpaConfig;
import de.all4cloud.scan4cloud.tenant.settings.SettingsService;

@Import(JpaConfig.class)
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages =
{ "de.myproject.project" }, exclude =
{ DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, FlywayAutoConfiguration.class })
public class SpringBootproject extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    @Autowired
    private SettingsService settingsService;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        return application.sources(SpringBootproject.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootproject.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public InitializingBean startupDevSettings()
    {
        return () ->
        {
            if (environment.getActiveProfiles().length == 0 || !environment.getActiveProfiles()[0].equals("production"))
            {
                settingsService.devSettings();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Line 40 is SpringApplication.run(SpringBootproject.class, args);

Comment: is that all the logs ?... and if this is your code then you might wanna investigate more on this line ```at de.myproject.project.SpringBootproject.main(SpringBootproject.java:40)```

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to tell where exact problem is, but

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException: null
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:51)
```

Is thrown when you have generic declaration with incorrect (or missing) type arguments. More specifically this declaration seems to be on method return type

```
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:255)
```

Check for compiler warnings `uses unchecked or unsafe operations.`

Here is an example of such problem:

```
public interface Api {
    List<String> methodA();
}

public class Impl implements Api {
    @Override
    List methodA() { return null; }  //here compiler will issue warning
}
```

Now when Spring try to figure out actual return type arguments of `methodA()` it will throw exception like in your case.

### Run your application in debug mode

You need to pass `--debug` argument to your program, Spring will be very verbose about what class/bean it is trying to create, which in turn should point to exact problem

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still facing the issue...
I had two versions of camel added to my `pom.xml`:

- `camel-spring-boot-starter`
- `camel-cxf`

So removing `camel-spring-boot-starter` solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks rkosegi.

I have tried different approaches. The --debug option didn't help therefore I started by clearing out all pom dependencies with maven enforcer plugin (mvn enforcer:enforce). Afterwards I was going through all the problems that existed in the project and solved one by one.

Now it is working again.